# Regular Expression not to allow numbers - just Arabic letters

Tags: regex, arabic

I found this regular expression for Arabic letters but it is also allowing numbers with letters. How can I change it to let it allow letters only ?

```
/[\u0600-\u06FF]/
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Probably you'd have to check what range the numbers match and exclude it (formally not include in brackets expression).

[Here](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/arabic.html) I've found another helpful source.

I'd suggest this for only letters

```
/[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF]/
```

as this matches arabic digits only

```
/[\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9]/
```

Edit:

I've found that there are two ranges for arabic and arabic-indic digits in unicode.

If you need a regex to match a line just then, when it contains arabic letters and numbers - use this:

```
/^[\u0600-\u06FF]*$/
```

If you want to also discourage arabic digits - use this:

```
/^[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF]*$/
```

If you want to match a substring, not only a whole line, use this:

```
/\b[\s\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF]*\b/
```

Comment: Thanks but this will include numbers 0-9 too

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are no westernized arabic digits as we use them 0-9 in the range `u0600-u06ff`. Check yourself [here](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/arabic.html). Maybe what you want, is a regex, that disallows a line where a number is contained. Gimme more context, so I could help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! yes you are right I don't want any numbers even english numbers. I just want regex to allow arabic string.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really appreciate your detailed answer.

Comment: All of the mentioned RegExes select English/Latin Letter too. How to exclude Latin characters?

Answer (score 7):

I tried all solutions provided here, nothing worked, finally one solution worked for me
for Arabic letters only

```
^[\u0621-\u064A\040]+$
```

Comment: this must be the solution

Answer (score 2):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "You can enter Arabic or English characters only")] 

[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "You can enter numbers only")]

[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\0-9]+$",ErrorMessage = "You can enter numbers or english characters only")]

[RegularExpression(@"^[\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669\0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "You can enter numbers or arabic characters only")]

[RegularExpression(@"^[\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669]+$", ErrorMessage = "You can enter arabic characters only")]

[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$",ErrorMessage = "You can enter english characters only")]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, concerning Arabic encoding in unicode, you might want to refer to this tables [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl)

As for the regex you were given, `[\u0600-\u06FF]` is the range of all arabic characters on the unicode listing, definitely that includes even letters, control characters, white-space, and numbers.

My recommendation would be:

```
/[\u0600-\u06FF&&[^\U06F0-\06F9]]/
```

Which spans just everything minus the arabic numeric digits (0-9).

That subtracts a range from the 'super' range. Am just not sure whether your target regex dialect supports this.

Comment: Thanks but I got this error: Invalid regular expression. Range out of order in character class.

Comment: just mistake in syntax. use: /[\u0600-\u06FF&&[^\u06F0-\u06F9]]/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this for only letters, words and sentences `[\sء-ي]+`

Comment: `[^` means, all chars in the class are forbidden.

Comment: oh sorry i forget to remove it. thanks for remainder @AndyA.