# Why this regex does not work with Eastern Arabic numerals?

Tags: javascript, regex

[@thg435](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/thg435) wrote this answer to a javascript [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229634/adding-class-to-the-nth-digit-of-numbers):

```
> a = "foo 1234567890 bbb 123456"
"foo 1234567890 bbb 123456"
> a.replace(/\d(?=\d\d(\d{3})*\b)/g, "[$&]")
"foo 1[2]34[5]67[8]90 bbb [1]23[4]56"
```

It works well with Hindu-Arabic numerals; i.e. 1,2,3,4,... . But when I try to apply the regex to Eastern Arabic numerals, it fails. Here is the regex I use (I've just replaced `\d` with `[\u0660-\u0669]` ):

```
/[\u0660-\u0669](?=[\u0660-\u0669][\u0660-\u0669]([\u0660-\u0669]{3})*\b)/g
```

It actually works if my string is `١٢٣٤foo`, but fails when it's `١٢٣٤ foo` or even `foo١٢٣٤`:

```
> a = "١٢٣٤foo  ١٢٣٤ foo  foo١٢٣٤"
"١٢٣٤foo  ١٢٣٤ foo  foo١٢٣٤"
> a.replace(/[\u0660-\u0669](?=[\u0660-\u0669][\u0660-\u0669]([\u0660-\u0669]{3})*\b)/g, "[$&]")
"١[٢]٣٤foo  ١٢٣٤ foo  foo١٢٣٤"
```

What actually matters to me are separated numbers (e.g. `١٢٣٤`). Why it cannot match separated numbers?

**Update:**

Another requirement is that the regex should only match numbers with 5 or more digits (e.g. ١٢٣٤٥ and not ١٢٣٤). I initially thought that that's as simple as adding `{5,}` at the end of the expression, but that doesn't work.

Comment: see http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/tr18-11.html

Comment: 1234567890 are actually arabic numerals ;)

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518689/regular-expression-not-to-allow-numbers-just-arabic-letters) might help

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, I'm experiencing the opposite behavior from you (the first one doesn't work and the other two do), but how about if you replaced the `\b` with `(?![\u0660-\u0669])`? Then it seems to work no matter what's before or after it:

```
[\u0660-\u0669](?=[\u0660-\u0669][\u0660-\u0669]([\u0660-\u0669]{3})*(?![\u0660-\u0669]))
```

**Edit:** This seems to work for the new requirement - to only add the brackets if the run of digits is 3 digits long or more:

```
[\u0660-\u0669](?=[\u0660-\u0669]{2}([\u0660-\u0669]{3})+(?![\u0660-\u0669]))|(?<=[\u0660-\u0669]{2})[\u0660-\u0669](?=[\u0660-\u0669]{2}(?![\u0660-\u0669]))
```

Incidentally, some Regex processors will treat those digits as a match for `\d`. Here is that second Regex with `\d` instead of those character ranges, which should be a little easier to read:

```
\d(?=\d{2}(\d{3})+(?!\d))|(?<=\d{2})\d(?=\d{2}(?!\d))
```

Comment: works well with nearly all regex engines except javascript's.. this is a problem with javascript's regex..also i have doubt about nested lookahead's support in javascript

Comment: This solved my problem. Only one simple more question: How can I only match 5 or more digits numbers (e.g. 12345 and not 1234)? Where should I add {5,}?

Comment: The new regex doesn't work. Can you please check the code, or create a jsfiddle?