# Replace only if the containing string length is greater than X

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a regex that will only match one character of the strings. I want to test the lentgh of its **containing string** and if it was greater than 4 then make the replacement. For example, the regex is `/\d/`. I want to use the functional form of replace to match `12345` but not `1234`.

Something like:

```
text.replace(regex, function(match) {
       if (STRING.length > 4)
            return replacement
       else
            return match;
  });
```

**Note:**
`/\d/` is just an example. I didn't mention the real regex to focus on my real question, illustrated above.

Comment: for all those like me who didn't know you could pass a function to the replace function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or if you want to do it that way:

```
function replaceWithMinLength (str, minLength) {
   str.replace(/\w+/, function(match) {
      if (match.length > minLength) {
        return match;
      } else {
        return str;
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: [**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/627rF/1/) is the original, and [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/627rF/2/) is trying to implementing your code.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem but I dont know what your actual goal is. Can you give the the result or wich characters should be red?

Comment: I probabely should have used a better example. Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/627rF/4/). The first line should not have any red character, as the number have less than five digits.

Comment: Also, if more information is needed, see [my previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241625/why-this-regex-does-not-work-with-eastern-arabic-numerals).

Comment: Ah, so it would make sense to check the length before applying the regex replace right? http://jsfiddle.net/XpjF2/

Comment: Thanks, but there's still a problem :)  [http://jsfiddle.net/XpjF2/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/XpjF2/2/)

Comment: Better illustrated here [http://jsfiddle.net/XpjF2/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/XpjF2/3/).

Comment: Ok, now im sure that this must be possible with regex. But with javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/7X7em/1/

Comment: Aslo, can you please tell me what do you think about its performance hit? Is this something to worry about?

Comment: Well I do not advise to use this method, but performance will not suffer that much I guess. Think of 3D canvas calculations browser do these days ;)

Answer (score 4):

You're putting the horse before the cart. You would be better off:

```
if(string.length > 4) {
  string.replace('needle','replacement');
}
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but… I think the OP would just have used `text` in that case. :)

Comment: the horse is supposed to be before the cart :)

Answer (score 0):

So by “containing string”, you mean like the same sequence of digits? Match them all at once:

```
text.replace(/\d{5,}/g, function(string) {
    return string.replace(/\d/g, function(match) {
        return replacement;
    });
});
```

For example. The `\d{5,}` can easily be adapted to any type of string-thing.

Comment: @Iryn: In what way? Can you show your code, or a [short example](http://codepen.io/pen)?

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241625/why-this-regex-does-not-work-with-eastern-arabic-numerals).

Comment: How to it for number. Example : How I would set all number below 40,000 to 0 in a text files *(they are delimited by commas semicolons full dots and spaces )*