# regex for Arabic and English letter(in viewmodel-c#)

Tags: c#, regex, viewmodel, arabic

I would like to have a regular expression that matches:

1.Arabic letters.

2.English letters.

3.Allow space.

4.min 2-max 30.

then i wrotre this regex:

`^(?:[a-zA-Z\s\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F\u08A0-\u08FF\uFB50-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF]|(?:\uD802[\uDE60-\uDE9F]|\uD83B[\uDE00-\uDEFF])[ ]{0,1}){2,30}$`

but its not good

Comment: If it doesn’t need to be specifically Arabic and English letters, but could be letters of any language you could just use `\P{L}` which would match any Unicode letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an Arabic letter regex is `[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF]` (see [Regular Expression not to allow numbers - just Arabic letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518689/)) and English letters are `[a-zA-Z]`, you can use

```js
^(?=.{2,30}$)[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FFa-zA-Z]+(?:\s[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FFa-zA-Z]+)?$
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{2,30}$)` - the string must be 2 to 30 chars long
- `[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FFa-zA-Z]+` - one or more Arabic or English letters
- `(?:\s[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FFa-zA-Z]+)?` - an optional occurrence of a whitespace and one or more Arabic or English letters
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks a lot!I changed abit and its ok
^([\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FFa-zA-Z]+[ ]{0,1}){2,30}$

Comment: @sara Just beware that this will also allow a space at the end of the string.